# Converting a gcp-hive table to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-platform, hive

I am trying to convert a gcp-hive table of 10000 rows to pandas dataframe. But after conversion it is showing only 1000 rows in my pandas dataframe.
There is a field with some text data in table, and it contains different language texts. And I am seeing only english in my dataframe and remaining nulls.
Could anyone help me understand the reduction in size of dataframe?

```
   text = %hive_dataproc select * from <table_name>;
```

is the code I am using for converting table to dataframe

Comment: Hi @Abhi, Can you provide the sample code that you have tried?

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, this issue is resolved, I added one line of code to remove the constraint of 1k rows.

Comment: Hi @Abhi, can you post your solution here so that it will help the community also?